# Mongodb data schema for this case

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I was testing out mongodb for one of my projects.

Basically i want to enter test scores for a number of students. So using mongodb, I started off with

```
db.grades.insert( {_id: 1024} );    // this references the student's SSN
db.grades.update( {_id: 1024}, { $push: { SemesterAssessment: 43 }} );    //insert student grades
db.grades.update( {_id: 1024}, { $push: { SemesterAssessment: 50 }} );  // teacher allows retaking

Output
{"SemesterAssessment : [43, 50], "_id": 1024};
```

I want to add a flag to the SemesterAssessment to indicate which grade reflects the latest test result.

I was looking to the following sample output:

```
Sample output
{"SemesterAssessment : [43, [latest: 50]], "_id": 1024}
```

This includes the key called 'latest'. But I'm not sure how to implement this in mongodb. Any one can help?

Comment: If you always push, then latest is always at the end of the array. 

You can get the last one by: `db.grades.find( {}, { SemesterAssessment: { $slice: -1 } } )`

Comment: Thanks orid, but i'm looking to mark a receive result as latest. On hindsight, should have used "approved" as a better word. Tim Gautier's answer is the nearest match to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{"SemesterAssessment" : [43, ["latest": 50]], "_id": 1024}
```

Isn't valid json, you'd need something like this:

```
({"SemesterAssessment" : [43, 50], "latest": 50}, "_id": 1024}
```

Then your code becomes this:

```
db.grades.insert( {_id: 1024} );
db.grades.update( {_id: 1024}, { $push: { SemesterAssessment: 43 }, 
    $set: { latest: 43 }});
db.grades.update( {_id: 1024}, { $push: { SemesterAssessment: 50 }, 
    $set: { latest: 50 }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using push it always add element at the end of the list and to find the latest element of an list you can use:

```
db.collection.find( { field: value }, { array: {$slice: count } } );
e.g    db.collection.find({},{arr:{$slice:-1}})
```

Comment: Hi Anuj, i'm looking to mark a receive result as latest. On hindsight, should have used "approved" as a better word. Tim Gautier's answer is the nearest match to my question. Thanks for your reply.